# seq vector of dates has type double but displayed as character

Tags: r

I am trying to set up a vector of dates in the last month in R. I want to loop through these dates and do stuff based on the date.

```
vector_of_dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-07-31")-30, as.Date("2019-07-31"), by = "days")
print(vector_of_dates)
```

This results in the following output. Looks good so far.

[image: printed dates]

However if I loop through the vector and print each element, I get numbers rather than dates.

```
for (date in vector_of_dates) {print(date)}
```

Here is a subset of the output. That seems odd.

[image: printed elements]

Furthermore if I try to interpret these as dates, I get an error.

```
for (date in vector_of_dates) {print(as.Date(date))}
```

Results in the following error.

[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using `in vectors` is akin to using `for(i in n)` instead of `i in 1:length(n)`. Try: `for(i in 1:length(vector_of_dates)) print(vector_of_dates[i])` or maybe `Map(as.Date,vector_of_dates)` and the like?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.r-bloggers.com/for-loops-in-r-can-lose-class-information/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) as.list** The `for` statement is stripping the class from the dates.   Convert the vector to a list to avoid this:

```
for(d in as.list(vector_of_dates)) print(d)
```

giving:

```
[1] "2019-07-01"
[1] "2019-07-02"
[1] "2019-07-03"
[1] "2019-07-04"
## ... etc ...
```

**2) index** Another approach is to iterate over an index:

```
for(i in seq_along(vector_of_dates)) print(vector_of_dates[i])
```

**3) lapply** We can use `lapply` rather than `for`:

```
junk <- lapply(vector_of_dates, print)
```

Also note that `c` has a `Date` method so that, for example, this will return a `Date` vector:

```
do.call("c", junk)
```